# Check weekend dates and color in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I need to play around with weekend dates identification and color the value in col M :

1. I need to check for "weekend dates" in Col K of sheet "Latency" (starting from row 2)
2. If a weekend date is found then check in Col O for the text "fail". If that is found,
3. Check for either of these three text "Moved to SA (Compatibility Reduction)" or "Text 2" or "Text 3" in Col P.
4. If either of these text is found and if the number in Col M is >1 then color it in red.

I have the below code that checks only for Sunday. But I want this to run for weekend and add additional keywords to check.

```
Sub SundayCheck()

Dim r, LastRow, RemainingDay As Double

LastRow = Range("M:O").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   For r = 2 To LastRow
      RemainingDay = 0

        If Weekday(Range("K" & r).Value, vbSunday) = 1 Then
                RemainingDay = Round((24 - Format(TimeValue(Range("K" & r)), "h")) / 24, 1)

             If InStr(1, Range("O" & r).Text, "Fail", vbTextCompare) > 0    Then

                 If Range("M" & r) - RemainingDay >= 1 Then
                     Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 3
                 Else
                     Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 0
                 End If

           End If
        End If
    Next r
     End Sub
```

Comment: you say 1) _"check in Col O for the text "fail""_ but your code checks for "pass" 2) _"if the number in Col M is >1 "_ but your code checks for `Range("M" & r) - RemainingDay >= 1`...

Comment: I edited point 1. Yes that check for the remaining hours. I want to remove this and add the conditions that i mentioned in the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the minimum editing of your code

```
Option Explicit

Sub SundayCheck()
    Dim r As Long, LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For r = 2 To LastRow
        If Weekday(Range("K" & r).Value, vbSunday) = 1 Or Weekday(Range("K" & r).Value, vbSunday) = 7 Then
           If UCase(Range("O" & r).Text) = "FAIL" Then
                Select Case True
                    Case InStr(Range("P" & r).Text, "Moved to SA (Compatibility Reduction)") > 0, _
                         InStr(Range("P" & r).Text, "Text2") > 0, _
                         InStr(Range("P" & r).Text, "Text3") > 0
                        If Range("M" & r) > 1 Then
                            Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 3
                        Else
                            Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 0
                        End If
                End Select
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Where I took your condition 3 as a full match instead of a partial one

Comment: Thanks for the edit..But for condition 3 I need a partial match..either one of those should match instead of all the three.

Comment: as code is now it checks for either one of three texts. the "full" match I wrote about is for the single string e.g: "Text2" would match while "abText2" wouldn't. BTW I edited the code and changed "fail" to "Moved to SA (Compatibility Reduction)" in the `Case` check

Comment: I dont know what I'm doing wrong But i'm not getting the result. My Col O has fail and Col M has "1.2" and Col P has the text "Moved to SA (Compatibility Reduction)". But "1.2" is not getting colored.

Comment: place a breakpoint at `If Range("M" & r) > 1 Then` and once your code stops there you open Immediate Window (CTRL+G), type `?Range("M" & r), Range("M" & r) > 1`, press return and see the outcome.

Comment: I got an error saying "Application -defined or object defined error" when I typed `?Range("M" & r), Range("M" & r) > 1` in the immediate window

Comment: you must first run the code and, once it stops at the breakpoint, you type what above

Comment: Yes I did the same..first set the breakpoint..then i pressed F5 inside the Sub then type in the immediate window

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134885/discussion-between-user3598756-and-stack-mark).